# Android Studio Errors moments after new project creation

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am try to create a simple hello world app for android. I created a new android project, with blank activity, the first thing I see is:

> Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent
>   version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "df94d6841b68f9e80ddebea52ebc092b1d66cb93" Fix plugin version and sync project
> Open
>   File

This I fixed after changing gradle wrapper properties to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip (it was 2.8 earlier)

Then I changed com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2 to beta2.

Atleast the gradle sync worked, so I decided to run the project. It compiled, pushed the apk to my device, followed by this crash :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.poketpixels.gcmfinal.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.poketpixels.gcmfinal-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                 at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
>                                                                                 Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.poketpixels.gcmfinal.MainActivity
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                         ... 13 more
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack available

- Why are there gradle version conflicts just after I create a fresh
         project.
- Why are there app crashes too ?

Answer (score 0):

First disconnect from a network before starting your android studio. After it's started you can now connect back to a network and update your sdk's.
Then take a cup of coffee.